# ASP.Net MVC 3 JsonValueProviderFactory issue with controller method which accepts array arg

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I am allowing JsonValueProviderFactory to populate the parameters of my controller action. One of the parameters is an array of *Cat*.
This works, but sometimes when there is only a single *Cat* it doesn't get passed in as an array, the argument is just *Cat*. I am using ExtJs, which is handling everything clientside.

Is there a way to handle this server-side? Or will I need to hack the request from ExtJs to force it to always send an array?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, IEnumerable<Cat> Data){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper JSON request should look like this if you have a single cat:

```
{ 'id': '123', 'Data': [ { 'Name': 'Felix', 'Age': 6 } ] }
```

and for multiple cats:

```
{ 'id': '123', 'Data': [ { 'Name': 'Felix', 'Age': 6 }, { 'Name': 'Morgan', 'Age': 2 } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC is attempting to bind the single instance of `Cat` to just that, an instance of `Cat` and not IEnumerable. Pass the array.

If you want to handle it server side, you could always:

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>;
cats.Add(argCat);
...
```

Since your controller argument is IEnumerable, it would seem you're expecting a set of data anyway. Maybe consider a separate controller action for the single instance if it makes business sense.